# Action bar sherlock importing in android asking to Select at least one project

Tags: android, import, actionbarsherlock

i am trying to import action bar sherlock i downloaded the project and i am following http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/setting-up-sherlock-library-for-action-bar-in-pre-honeycomb-android-applications/ As per the screen shot in site i attache my screen too but after selecting root directory it is asking me to select atleast one project why? Help will be thank ful...[image]

Comment: first checkout whether your workspace consist of same named project or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a directory can contain more than one project, eclipse offers a dialog where you can choose which project you want to import.

Actionbarsherlock contains, as far as I remember, a library and an example folder. The library folder is the one you want to import.

So simply select the library project and then link that one to the project you want to use it in. (you can of course also rename the project in eclipse after importing it, as "library" isn't really descriptive.

Comment: The one you posted. you have to select at least one project. So simply check the checkbox for the library entry and then you can import the actionbar sherlock library.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I know this is old, but I just ran into the same issue after trying to update to the new 4.3.1 version of the ABS library. The problem was simple to solve though, and it had to do with the fact that I already had a library project with the same name.

I downloaded the zip file. So just renaming the folder originally called actionbarsherlock to actionbarsherlock-4.3.1 did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

**In Eclipse:**
you may be added this project to your workspace already. to check it, just control in Package Explorer if project already exists or not.
You can simply remove project if you want and add it again.